# Induction loop for catching lightning?

Tags: inductance, coil, lightning

Recent thunderstorm, and a big overhead cloud to cloud lightning flash. Coincident with it, sparks jumped from a metal chair in the house. Would it be possible to get a spark from a loop of cable layed on the floor in the form of a coil with the ends open to create a small spark gap? Or would it have to be more carefully tuned than that? The idea is to get some sparks from lightning that is further away.

Comment: why do you think people have surge protection devices around?

Comment: The real trick is not getting sparks but avoiding  getting electrocuted. Seriously don't play with lightning - you only get it wrong once.

Comment: Yes, I better not hold my arms in a circle with first fingers pointed at each other in a saline loop during a thunderstorm, while indoors, or I might get electrocuted. Does that REALLY sound plausible to you guys? Because it is the exact same configuration above.

Comment: My kitchen faucet sparks during thunderstorms. It's because of poor grounding, the pipes act like such a loop and a spark jumps between the faucet and sink when the water is running. I expect you would need a loop about as big around as your house to achieve what you suggest. I expect the voltage was not induced in the chair, but rather it was induced in the water pipes or something of the sort, and the chair simply got close enough to the pipes to get a spark.

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly diff. approch..and my assumptions may find little weird..but we have find out why did it happen..
1. generally to break 1cm air gap 10000V would be sufficient. there is a capacitance (assuming it is isolated from ground!)from chair to ground which is proportinal to the area of chair/distance of chair from ground. There is a capacitance of the cloud to ground inversely proportional to distance from ground. If cloud is at very very low altitude and the static voltage on the cloud is more than 1000000 volts then it can produce electrostatic voltage in the chair. moment cloud charge gets discharged the trapped charge on the chair may be sufficiently high to break air dielectric.
2. these being electrostaitc phenomenon I doubt whether an electromagnetic solution may not help being current dependent.
vtinole

Comment: The voltage must have been getting on towards 100kV just from the length, which was a minimum of around 5cm

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea..vtingole

Answer (score 0):

Is it theoretically possible to create a loop that will catch a glimpse of the EM wave generated by a powerful spark somewhere far away? Yes.

Is it theoretically possible to create that loop such that it will induce a voltage large enough to create a spark itself, be it very low in intensity (rule of cubes concerning the EM energy, and what not)? Yes.

Is it practically applicable? No.

Why not? Things like exact orientation and configuration depend greatly on the location and distance of the discharge. You'd need prior knowledge of the flash to create and position the coil such that it would successfully induce each time.

What happened with the chair?
More likely than not in the thunderstorm the air was slightly dry in your house, allowing static build up in the chair, then creating a spark. Again, it is theoretically possible the chair "picked up" the flash, but the statistics against are astronomical.
What is much more likely to happen is that somewhere in the world someone at the same time as a lightning strike sees a static spark go from a chair.

It is very normal for the mind to infer a connection, and there may well be, but further testing would be required. Considering the huge amount of lightning strikes a day and the staggering world population,....

It's just, ... this time it was you.

Comment: It happened twice and the sparks were cm in length. The lightning, judging from flash to sound, must have been within 100m

Comment: Proximity makes it more likely. As I said, I could have been what happened. It may need priming, it may not. Doesn't change the fact that it's a coincidence of location and direction. Had the chair toppled over between sparks the second would probably not have happened.

Comment: The sparks exceeded 5cm at a guess and could have been up to 10cm

Comment: Well aside from all the depressive talk; you can actually violate the rule of squares/cubes by applying a 3*10^8/f charge to a coil and coupling the near field to whatever it is you want to spark to, provided that is coupled too, and provided your f yields a wavelength equal to the distance between the two. It's not actually a violation, but you aren't emanating energy from a point source, you are expanding the point size to 10 or whatever meters and the charge sits on the edge.